# How To Separate Index from userInput and add(+) them as INT in While Loop?

Tags: python, algorithm

condition is:

input any number from the user (it can be 4 digits or five or whatever)
e.g. '1234'
it will be in string
what I have to do is just separate those numbers and do the addition of those indexes as int

I have done this

```py
usrInput = input("Type a number you want to some: ")
    
len = len(usrInput)
    
n = 0
    
i = 1
    
while i<=len:
    index = int(usrInput[n]) #1
    n+=1
    i+=1
```

---

Now if I print(index) it will separate those numbers into separated index

now, how can I do the addition of them in this while loop.

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You seem to be able to add numbers already. Perhaps you could take a guess about how its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can individually access the values from the string. Going with your approach, if you want to get the sum of all the numbers, all you have to do is initialize a variable to 0 and add the numbers as you iterate through them in the loop. 
In your program you had used two variables `i` and `n` to basically perform the same task. You don't need two separate variables to access the value from the string and increment the loop.

```
usrInput = input("Type a number you want to add: ")
sumval = 0
i = 0

while i< len(usrInput):
    index = int(usrInput[i]) #1
    sumval+=index
    i+=1

print(sumval)
```